# NullDisplayText Data Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have an MVC application and I am trying to assign the `NullDisplayText` property to fields in my model, but am not getting any results.

Here is a portion of my model with the data attribute, where a null value should cause the output "(None)"...

```
Public Class Task
    ...
    <DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText:="(None)", ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=True)>
    Public Property EstimatedPrice As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    ...
End Class
```

When I access this property in my view (strongly typed to Task of course) like so...

```
@ModelType ProjectName.Task
@Html.ValueFor(Function(model) model.EstimatedPrice)
```

The debugger says `model.EstimatedPrice = Nothing` but the output is nothing. Why is the `NullDisplayText` attribute not correctly working here?

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: What does it say if you just try to output @model.EstimatedPrice

Comment: Ah, Thats right, I think you have to use the DisplayFor helper if I am not mistaken @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.EstimatedPrice) for the DisplayFormat stuff to work

Comment: Hey that totally worked, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Awesome, I don't use this as much as I should, thus the comment.  Posted as an answer so that we can mark this as solved.  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `<DisplayFormat>` attribute to apply in the view, you have to use the `@Html.DisplayFor` and `@Html.EditorFor` helpers. For example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.EstimatedPrice)
```